# Applying aspects depending on advised object invocation place

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

Please consider the following: we have a Spring bean `B` which is advised with a number of aspects: `A1`, `A2`. We have some other Spring beans: `X`, `Y`, `Z` — and `B` is injected to all of them. The question is: how can we make aspects of `B` to be applied or not depending on bean from which `B` is invoked (`X`, `Y`, `Z`)? In my particular task I need to make one aspect (for example, `A2`) to be bypassed when `B` is invoked from particular bean (for example, `Z`), while in other invocations all aspects must be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision was quite simple. `Z` contains the reference to `B`, and this reference is of type `Advised`. This interface allows accessing different properties of advised object, including its aspects. This allows creating new advised object which includes only needed aspects of `B`. The code snippet follows.

All types and identifiers are given in respect to example from the original question. `B` is ab interface, `b` is a reference. Code snippet is from `Z` bean.

```
Class<?>[] classes = {B.class};
AdvisedSupport config = new AdvisedSupport(classes);
try {
    config.setTargetSource(((Advised) b).getTargetSource());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for (Advisor advisor : ((Advised) b).getAdvisors()) {
    Advice advice = advisor.getAdvice();
    if ((advice instanceof AbstractAspectJAdvice) && "advice.A2".equals(
            ((AbstractAspectJAdvice) advice).getAspectName())) {
        // Do not add A2 advisor
    } else {
        config.addAdvisor(advisor);
    }
}
DefaultAopProxyFactory factory = new DefaultAopProxyFactory();
B newB = (B)factory.createAopProxy(config).getProxy();
```

Now `newB` reference is ready for use.